# FancyVerb error for Sweave output in Beamer

Tags: beamer, verbatim, sweave

I'm having trouble including Sweave output in my Beamer file. Specifically, the `Soutput` environment is causing problems (it runs if I comment those lines out, but, of course, the table is not presented as a single row and in standard font). Here is the basic file:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{Sweave}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Comparison}
\begin{Schunk}
\begin{Soutput}
  Gender Admitted Rejected
1 Female        6        6
2   Male        6        6
\end{Soutput}
\end{Schunk}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And the error in its gory detail:

```
ERROR: FancyVerb Error:

--- TeX said ---
  Extraneous input `Gender Admitted Rejected 1 Female 6 6 2 Male 6 6 \end {Soutput} \end {Schunk} \end {beamer@frameslide}\ifbeamer@twoscreenstext \beamer@dosecondscreennow {{Comparison} \begin {Schunk} \begin {Soutput} Gender Admitted Rejected 1 Female 6 6 2 Male 6 6 \end {Soutput} \end {Schunk} }\fi \ifbeamer@anotherslide \advance \beamer@slideinframe by 1\relax \relax \expandafter \iterate \fi \let \iterate \relax \beamer@writeslidentry \beamer@reseteecodes ' between \begin{Soutput}[<key=value>] and line end
.
\FV@Error ... {FancyVerb Error:
\space \space #1
}

l.13 \end{frame}

--- HELP ---
From the .log file...

This input will be discarded. Hit <return> to continue.
```

Thanks for any assistance that you can provide.

Comment: I don't use sweave, so I can't test, but does starting the frame with `\begin{frame}[fragile]` help?

Comment: Yes, thank you! I'll have to find out more about the `fragile` option for the `frame` environment.

Comment: Note that it is unusual around here to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it) or to have any greeting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the beamer manual (section 12.9 *Verbatim and Fragile Text* in version 3.10):

> If you wish to use a `{verbatim}`
>   environment in a frame, you have to
>   add the option `[fragile]` to the
>   `{frame}` environment. In this case, you
>   really have to use the `{frame}`
>   environment (not the `\frame` command)
>   and the `\end{frame}` must be alone on a
>   single line.

So all you have to do is to replace `\begin{frame}` by `\begin{frame}[fragile]`.