# Using fancyvrb to create a new verbatim environment in Isabelle

Tags: environments, verbatim, fancyvrb

Following answer

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114672/27523

I used fancyvrb to define a new verbatim environment -- I will use it to specify some font later, now I want to make it work at all.

I use the Isabelle document preparation system that generates LaTeX code from Isabelle theory files.

I have the following in `root.tex` in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\newenvironment{jeditoutput}
{
 \Verbatim
}
{
 \endVerbatim
}
```

That file includes the generated LaTeX.

In the Isabelle theory file there is

```
\begin{jeditoutput}
proof (prove)
goal (1 subgoal):
 1. True 
Auto solve_direct: The current goal can be solved directly with
  HOL.TrueI: True
\end{jeditoutput}
```

Now, I get the error

```
*** \FV@Error ... {FancyVerb Error:

*** \space \space #1

*** }

***

*** l.61 \end{jeditoutput} %%
```

Searching for the error message I have found some questions here on tex.stackexchange.com . One of them,

[FancyVerb error when % at end, when using \DefineVerbatimEnvironment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280230/fancyverb-error-when-at-end-when-using-defineverbatimenvironment)

suggests that a space should be added after ending jeditoutput. I tried this, even

```
\end{jeditoutput} %
```

but it did not work.

Another

[FancyVerb error for Sweave output in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11608/fancyverb-error-for-sweave-output-in-beamer)

suggests that in Beamer one should use the `fragile` option for the `frame` environment.

But this is no Beamer, still, it gave the hint that there is something with the enclosing environment.

Taking a look what happens under the hood, here is the jeditoutput section in the generated LaTeX file:

```
\begin{isamarkuptext}%
We have given a name for this theorem: \emph{true}. The system's output     console
displays the following message:

\begin{jeditoutput}
proof (prove)
goal (1 subgoal):
 1. True
Auto solve_direct: The current goal can be solved directly with
  HOL.TrueI: True
\end{jeditoutput} %%
\end{isamarkuptext}\isamarkuptrue%
```

The `isamarkuptext` environment is defined as

```
\newcommand{\isastyletext}{\normalsize\rm}

...

\newcommand{\isabeginpar}{\par\ifisamarkup\relax\else\medskip\fi}
\newcommand{\isaendpar}{\par\medskip}
\newenvironment{isapar}{\parindent\isa@parindent\parskip\isa@parskip\isabeginpar}{\isaendpar}
\newenvironment{isamarkuptext}{\par\isastyletext\begin{isapar}}{\end{isapar}}
```

Having these, do you see what is causing the `FancyVerb Error` ?

How can I make this new verbatim environment work through the Isabelle document preparation system?

Comment: @egreg , what do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the original answer

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114672/27523

there is another solution

```
\usepackage{verbatim,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{myverbA}
  {\verbatim}
  {\endverbatim}
```

that worked in my case. I might run into problems specifying a font but the basic case works.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want something like this:

```
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\newenvironment{jeditoutput}
{
 \VerbatimEnvironment
 \begin{Verbatim}%
}
{
 \end{Verbatim}%
}
```

The `\VerbatimEnvironment` tells `fancyvrb` to look for `\end{jeditoutput}` as the end of the environment, rather than `\end{Verbatim}`. Then you can proceed to use the normal `fancyvrb` environment. The `%` prevent extra spaces from being inserted after `}`. In a case like this, that should only be important if you have additional code to add at the beginning or end of the environment.

Comment: unfortunately it does not work, I have the same error message as before.

Comment: @Gergely If you still have `%%` right after the end of the environment (`\end{jeditoutput} %%`), you will want to remove them, so that `\end{jeditoutput}` is on a line by itself.